# 'Stand Alone' Controllers VS modular controllers in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am new to angularJS.  I have been reading many code examples and I often see controllers defined as:

```
    function MyController($scope) {
            //code here
    };
```

I however am using the method below to define my controller, as I wasn't aware there was any other way to do it.

```
angular.module("csApp.controllers", [])
    .controller("main", function ($scope) {
//code here
};
```

How does the first method work?  Is there some sort of naming convention I am missing here?

Are people using the first method simply adding these functions as global variables by placing them in in script files after angular loads?

How would you connect a global variable to a route if the controller is not registered with angularJS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AngularJS Dependency Injection framework can always find controller constructor function in global scope as they are global by nature. Even the `ng-controller` directive has this in its documentation

> Name of a globally accessible constructor function or an expression
>   that on the current scope evaluates to a constructor function.

When using `$routeProvider` you can provide the route definition a Controller class or a quoted controller name which has been registered using the module api. These two are valid

```
route :{controller:MainCtrl,...}
route :{controller:'main',...}
```

The module based approach is preferable because it stops one from polluting the JS global namespace.

Comment: Great!  This will be so much easier to keep track of!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize your module, then you can declare your controllers with the two methods.

The first method make it easier and more readable when you have for instance 5 controllers, or if you want to split them in differents files. But they do the same job. All you need to do is keeping track your controller name.

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
    // do your stuff
}

<!-- Using the function name here -->
<ANY ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <!-- your HTML data -->
</ANY>
```

More info in the [API Doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angController).

Comment: So there are just plain old global javascript functions?

Comment: Yup, it's just ordinary JS functions.